# error while inserting data inside mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

```
String pass=new String(pf1.getPassword());

try {
    Connection myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject","root","noor1032");
    PreparedStatement myStat=myConn.prepareStatement("insert into user_info (username,password,email_id)"+"values(?,?,?)");
    myStat.setString(1, tf1.getText());
    myStat.setString(2, pass);
    myStat.setString(3, tf2.getText());
    myStat.execute();
    myConn.close();
}   
catch(Exception f)
{
    System.err.println("Got an exception!");
    System.err.println(f.getMessage());
}
```

I want to insert data entered by user in a JFrame to my sql database. `tf1` and `tf2` are textfields for username and email_id, respectively. When I execute this statement an exception occurs saying that

```
Field 'id' does not have a default value
```

`id` is a column in my database denoting numbers like 1,2,3 and so on. Please help me.

Comment: Can u please share your table structure and try this first.  Connection myConn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject","root","noor1032");
    PreparedStatement myStat=myConn.prepareStatement("insert into user_info (username,password,email_id)"+"values(?,?,?)");
    myStat.setString(1, "abc");
    myStat.setString(2, "def");
    myStat.setString(3, "ghi");
    myStat.execute();
    myConn.close();

Comment: Is `id` an `auto_incremented` field which is the primary key?

Comment: Evidently your `user_info` table has an `id` column without a default value, so you can't add a row to the table without specifying what value `id` should have.

Comment: how to increment id automatically??

Comment: "how to increment id automatically?? " auto_increment?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: actually this link is about auto incrementing through myd=sql commands.....i am asking how to increment them through java code.....actually i dont know wmysql

Comment: @JashandeepSingh See my answer. If you set `id` to `auto_increment` this will automatically be handled by your java code and db.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ID as Auto Increment in mysql .It will work

Comment: You can do it using mysql command as Giorgos Myrianthous say .

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't shared your table's structure, I guess that `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` but you missed `AUTO_INCREMENT` configuration. In your database, run the following statement

```
ALTER TABLE user_info MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment
```